# How to build a git repo with external submodules in a vNext build on an on-premises TFS 2017?

Tags: git, authentication, tfs, azure-devops, git-submodules

**Given:**

1. Repo 1
2. Repo 2
3. Repo X - loads Repos 1 and 2 as submodules

People make commits independently to Repo 1 and Repo 2, but never Repo X.

I need to create a vNext build for Repo X.

**Problem:**

Nobody updates Repo X, i.e. nobody runs the following commands:

1. git submodule update --recursive --remote
2. git add .
3. git commit "Refreshed"
4. git push

I do not want humans to be aware of this detail, hence I want the build do it as the first step.

However, the problem is authentication - how do I make the build authenticate with the TFS server?

**I do not want any interactivity, even once at the very beginning.**

So, I create user name and password build variables (the latter is a secret), but now I am at loss - how do I make them propagate to git?

The only non interactive option I can see is the askpass protocol. But that implies writing some code, which seems trivial, but I wish to avoid it, if possible.

So, my question is - is there a better way to build Repo X? The one that does not force me to manipulate the Repo X explicitly from the build itself? If not, is there a simple way to authenticate with the TFS server without any user interaction whatsoever?